# SQL Server can't execute

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

There is a problem in my database when I execute this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCombine" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Product] WHERE [ProductId] = @ProductId" 
     InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Product] ([ProductName], [ProductDescription], [ProductCategory], [ProductBrand], [ProductPrice], [ProductQty], [ProductUploadDate]) VALUES (@ProductName, @ProductDescription, @ProductCategory, @ProductBrand, @ProductPrice, @ProductQty, @ProductUploadDate)"  
     SelectCommand="SELECT Product.*, ProductCategory.*, ProductBrand.*
                    FROM Product 
                    INNER JOIN ProductCategory AS PC ON Product.ProductCategory = ProductCategory.CategoryId     
                    INNER JOIN ProductBrand AS PB ON Product.ProductBrand = ProductBrand.BrandId" 
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Product] SET [ProductName] = @ProductName, 
                        [ProductDescription] = @ProductDescription, 
                        [ProductCategory] = @ProductCategory, 
                        [ProductBrand] = @ProductBrand, 
                        [ProductPrice] = @ProductPrice, 
                        [ProductQty] = @ProductQty, 
                     WHERE [ProductId] = @ProductId">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: In the `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection`, do you have the `Initial Catalog` set? If so, is that set to the same db that the `[Product]` table is in? Is the `[Product]` table in the `dbo` schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple mistakes in your queries specified.

- First your SELECT query uses `Product` just before last inner join which is wrong syntax. So, use the following query for select command.

**SELECT query**

```
SELECT product.*, 
       productcategory.*, 
       productbrand.* 
FROM   product 
       INNER JOIN productcategory 
               ON product.productcategory = productcategory.categoryid 
       INNER JOIN productbrand 
               ON product.productbrand = productbrand.brandid
```

- Second, your UPDATE query has a comma just before WHERE which again is wrong syntax. Use query below for update command.

**Update query**

```
UPDATE [product] 
SET    [productname] = @ProductName, 
       [productdescription] = @ProductDescription, 
       [productcategory] = @ProductCategory, 
       [productbrand] = @ProductBrand, 
       [productprice] = @ProductPrice, 
       [productqty] = @ProductQty 
WHERE  [productid] = @ProductId
```

Your final markup should be as below.

**SqlDataSource with corrected queries**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCombine" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Product] WHERE [ProductId] = @ProductId" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Product] ([ProductName], [ProductDescription], [ProductCategory], [ProductBrand], [ProductPrice], [ProductQty], [ProductUploadDate]) VALUES (@ProductName, 
       @ProductDescription, @ProductCategory, @ProductBrand, @ProductPrice, @ProductQty, @ProductUploadDate)"  
   SelectCommand="SELECT product.*,  productcategory.*, 
     productbrand.*  FROM   product 
   INNER JOIN productcategory 
   ON product.productcategory = productcategory.categoryid 
   INNER JOIN productbrand 
   ON product.productbrand = productbrand.brandid "
   UpdateCommand="UPDATE [product] 
    SET    [productname] = @ProductName, 
    [productdescription] = @ProductDescription, 
    [productcategory] = @ProductCategory, 
    [productbrand] = @ProductBrand, 
    [productprice] = @ProductPrice, 
    [productqty] = @ProductQty 
    WHERE  [productid] = @ProductId ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```